# Compass watch with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'd like to create a task to watch all my scss files. And I used "grunt-contrib-watch" and "grunt-contrib-sass" but it doesn't work.

My files and my directories : http://glui.me/?i=pz7vmwu9cfgbzt3/2013-11-28_at_12.46_2x.png/

My error :

```
MacBook-Pro-of-username:src username:src$ grunt
Running "cssmin:minify" (cssmin) task
File lib/stylesheets/bottom.min.css created.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...Bus error: 10
```

My grunt code :

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'lib/stylesheets/bottom.css' : 'lib/sass/bottom.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
            minify: {
                files: [{
                    'lib/stylesheets/bottom.min.css': ['lib/stylesheets/bottom.css']
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with node <= 0.10.20 and OSX mavericks. Upgrade node.js to the latest and it should fix the issue. See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/204